# Understanding proof of $\mathbb{E}[X^n] = \int_{0}^\infty n x^{n-1} (1 - F(x)) dx$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, cumulative-distribution-functions

For a nonnegative random variable $X$ with CDF $F$ and $n \geq 1$,

$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X^n] &= \int_{0}^\infty x^n d F(x)\\
&= \int_{0}^\infty \left ( \int_{0}^x n y^{n-1} dy \right ) d F(x) \\
&= \int_{0}^\infty \int_{y}^\infty ny^{n-1} dF(x) dy\\
&= \int_{0}^\infty n y^{n-1}(1 - F(y)) dy
\end{align*}$

1. I have not seen the notation in the first equality before. All I know is $\mathbb{E}[X^n] = \int_{0}^\infty x^n f_X(x) dx$ but I know the pdf $f_X$ does not necessarily exist. What does $dF(x)$ in the first equality mean?
2. How to go from second to third equality? Interchanging the order of integrals should give $\int_{0}^x \int_{0}^\infty$; how to understand the new limits?
3. The 4th equality apparently uses the result $1 - F(y) = \int_{y}^\infty dF(x)$ which I don't understand because I don't know what $dF(x)$ means in the first place.

Comment: The notation stands for the [Riemann-Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann–Stieltjes_integral). It can also be seen as the integral with respect to the [pushforward measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure) $$\mathsf P_X\overset{\text{Def.}}=\mathsf P\circ X^{-1},$$ where $X^{-1}(x)=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)=x\}$

Comment: As for your first and third question, look for phrase: Riemann-Stieltjets integral. As for the second one, notice: you're integrating set $\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R_+^2 : y<x \} = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R_+^2 : y <x , x\in \mathbb R_+ \} = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R_+^2 : x>y , y \in \mathbb R_+ \}$. So that after swapping your inner one is for $x >y$, and the outer for $y \in \mathbb R_+$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First a few things about CDF. Let $X$ be any random variable and $F$ be the CDF of $X.$ What we know about $F$ is that $F$ is increasing, right-continuous, and $F(-\infty)=0=1-F(\infty).$ Since $F$ is an increasing function; writing $dF(x)$ makes perfect sense, that is, we can integrate (Reimann-Stiltjes integral) with respect to $F,$ and it is not hard to show that if $X$ has a density $f_X$ then $dF(x)=f_X(x)dx.$

Now, the first equality is nothing but the definition. If you want to be more rigorous: Let $X$ be a random variable on some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu),$ and $h:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be any function such that $h(X)\in L^1(\mu),$ then $\mathbb{E}(h(X)):=\int_{\Omega}h(X)(\omega)d\mu(\omega).$ Now a simple change of variable tells us that $\mathbb{E}(h(X))=\int_{\mathbb{R}}h(x)d\mu_X(x)$ where $\mu_X$ is the distribution of $X,$ in other words, $\mu_X$ is a measure on $\mathbb{R}$ defined as $\mu_X(A):=\mu(X^{-1}(A)).$ You can take $dF(x)$ to mean the measure $d\mu_X,$ in fact for any measure on radon measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ one can associate a distribution function $F_{\mu}$ such that the integral with respect to $\mu$ is same as the Stiltjes integral with respect to the distribution function $F_{\mu}.$

With all this technicality in mind, now the first equality is just the definition. The second equality is a simple verification, you can check. The third equality is Fubini's theorem (to be honest Tonelli's theorem, and this is where we use that $X$ is non-negative), and hence you can change the order of integration. And, once you get around what $dF(x)$ means, you know that your third statement is indeed true, and you know why.

Comment: It should be noted that when $X$ is not positive, the equality $$\mathsf{E}(X^n)= \int_{0}^\infty x^n \,\mathrm d F(x)$$ doesn't hold in general, so positivity of $X$ is used here also

Comment: $h \in L^1 \Leftrightarrow \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |h(x)| dx  < \infty$. What does"$\in L^1(\mu)$" mean? Can you write it down? Thanks.

Comment: $h\circ X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is said to be in $L^1(\mu)$ if $\int_{\Omega}|h\circ X|d\mu<\infty.$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch You are right. But, for any random variable $X$ we still have that $\mathbb{E}(X^n)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} x^n dF(x).$ The fact that $X\ge 0$ gives us that $F(x)=0$ for all $x<0,$ so in that case, we essentially get the first equality.